# Cassandra v3.0.9 bootstrap failing

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are running a Cassandra cluster with close to 30 nodes. We are in the process of scaling the cluster to about 40. The cluster currently runs on AWS in `us-east1` AZ (1b, 1e & 1d).

Configuration for bootstrap:

- `auto_bootstrap: true` (Default)
- `-Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false` (Default)

The bootstrap seems to be complete with all the nodes streaming data to this new node. Yet, the node seems to stay in `JOINING` state and bootstrapping eventually is timing out (after 3 hrs; `streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms`). This is an inconsistent state with the new node being stuck in `UJ` state forever.

I tried `nodetool bootstrap resume` which also hangs indefinitely. I checked `nodetool netstats` and none of the nodes are streaming data to the new node.

Now, since I know I have all the data that belongs to this node, I try to add `auto_bootstrap: false` in the `cassandra.yaml` and restart `cassandra` process. My expectation was that adding `auto_bootstrap: false` will not bother about streaming data from other nodes, but seems like I am missing something here. The node seems to receive data from other nodes and the bootstrapping is starting all over again.

I went another step ahead and tried by adding the `-Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false` along with the `auto_bootstrap: false` (I did this as I intermittently got `RuntimeException` suggesting `A node required to move the data consistently is down` although all the nodes were `UN`). I still see that the node tries to stream data from other nodes. Am I missing something here.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out here. Happy to provide with any other details if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1)-Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false should be used while bootstrapping multiple nodes in parallel. And it can violate consistency. Safest way is add one at a time.

2)If node is UJ and no streaming is going, then steaming has stopped due to some error, check the node system.log, streaming will also be stopped when the other nodes are stopped/restarted when streaming is in progress.

3)You can delete the data and restart the node which will start streaming the data again. After node is UN check the "nodetool compactionstats". After pending compaction process is completed, run "nodetool repair -pr" and "nodetool cleanup" on each node one after another.